# how to run a function/sub after loading the form window in VB?

Tags: vb.net

I have a function that gets User ID from USB badge reader, used to log in an application. 
when I run the app, the log in window does not appear until I swipe the tag.
I need to know if it`s possible to load the windows, then to start running the function that gets the data from the USB.

Thanks :)

```
Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived()
    'Threading.Thread.SpinWait(1000)
    OpenPort()
    If SerialPort1.IsOpen() Then

        byteEnd = SerialPort1.NewLine.ToCharArray
        'read entire string until .Newline 
        readBuffer = SerialPort1.ReadLine()
        readBuffer = readBuffer.Remove(0, 1)
        readBuffer = readBuffer.Remove(8, 1)
        WWIDTextBox.AppendText(readBuffer)

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Activated(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Activated
    SerialPort1_DataReceived()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'SerialPort1_DataReceived()
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to block user input on the form until it is swiped, or do you want the form to accept input?  Presumably you are calling a blocking (synchronous) method to read the badge.  Does the API for the badge reader provide any equivalent asynchronous method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling the `ReadLine` method, which is a blocking (synchronous) method.  In other words, when you call it, the method does not return the value until it has the value to return.  Because of that, it stops execution on the current thread until a complete line is read (when the badge is swiped).  Since you are on the UI thread when you call it, it will lock up the UI until the badge is swiped.

Instead of calling your `SerialPort1_DataReceived` method from the UI thread, you can do the work from a different thread.  The easiest way to do that is to drag a `BackgroundWorker` component onto your form in the designer.  Then you can add code like this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    OpenPort()
    If SerialPort1.IsOpen() Then
        byteEnd = SerialPort1.NewLine.ToCharArray
        Dim readBuffer As String = SerialPort1.ReadLine()
        readBuffer = readBuffer.Remove(0, 1)
        readBuffer = readBuffer.Remove(8, 1)
        e.Result = readBuffer
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    WWIDTextBox.AppendText(CStr(e.Result))
End Sub
```

Comment: I have another question, how can I "restart" it ? if I log in and log out, then i can`t use the badge reader again!

Comment: Are you saying that restarting the application works, but showing the login form twice within the same process does not?

Comment: yes, but just to be clear, i`m using Hide() and Show() methods to open and "close" windows. using Close() closes the app.

Comment: It's hard to say why, without seeing more of the code.  I'm have no experience specifically with the `SerialPort` class, or, obviously, that reader, so I probably wouldn't be able to figure it out definitively anyway.

Comment: Thank you man anyways, with Application.Restart it works fine for me. but I have to say, without your help I am probably stuck at the same problem. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Working on VS2013, I came across the same issue, I needed to to a datagridview refresh (colors in the gridrows).  This worked for me.

```
Sub MyForm_VisibleChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.VisibleChanged

            If Me.Visible Then
                'do action...
            End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [Form Activated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activated%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) Event

```
Private Sub Form1_Activated(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Activated
 'Call your function here
End Sub
```

It call the function `After the Form Loads`...

Comment: That will still lock up the UI until the badge is swiped, however.

Comment: still not working. it waits until readUsbPort timeout is reached, then it shows the form window.

Comment: @user2234234 : Remove the code `SerialPort1_DataReceived()` from `Form_Load` event and try the same...

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub loadCombo()
    Dim sqlconn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim connString As String
    connString = ""
    Dim access As String
    access = "select slno from atable"
    Dim DataTab As New DataTable
    Dim DataAdap As New OleDbDataAdapter(access, connString)
    DataAdap.Fill(DataTab)
    ComboBox1.DataSource = DataTab
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "slno"

End Sub
```

Comment: How to write code for onload() function,it might be very useful for  freshers.